# An integer programming on maximum number of triangles

Tags: integer-programming

Consider three distinct sets $A, B, C$ of $N$ elements respectively. For each pair of sets, say $A,B$, we introduce an variable for each combination of values $a,b$ as $x_{ab}$. Similarly, we introduce a variable $y_{bc}$ for each $b \in B, c \in C$, and $z_{ac}$ for each $a \in A$, $c \in C$.

Consider the following integer programming with the optimal solution as $OPT$.

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \max \sum _{a \in A, b \in B, c \in C} x_{ab} \cdot y_{bc} \cdot z_{ac}$$
$$s.t. \sum_{a \in A, b \in B} x_{ab} \le N$$
$$\ \ \ \ \sum_{b \in B, c \in C} y_{bc} \le N$$
$$\ \ \ \ \sum_{a \in A, c \in C} z_{ac} \le N$$
$$x_{ab}, y_{bc}, z_{ac} \in \{0,1\}, \forall a \in A, b \in B, c \in C$$

Is the following decision problem polynomial-time solvable or NP-hard:
Given an input integer $k$, whether $OPT > k$ or not?

Comment: I think the maximum value is $N^{3/2}$. Each of the three conditions form a relation of size $N$. Given three relations $R(a,b), S(b,c), T(a,c)$, you can use AGM bound to upper bound the join size (which is number of triangles) as $N^{3/2}$. This bound is tight. You can see that by choosing $\sqrt{N}$ values in $A,B,C$ and forming a cartesian product. Take a look at worst-case optimal join in database literature.

Comment: The $N^{3/2}$ is just an asymptotically tight upper bound, but not exact bound. How about when $\sqrt{N}$ is not a integer?

Comment: Since you ask about time poly$(N)$, and the only input is $N$, I assume you intend that $N$ is encoded in unary (so the input size is $N$).  Also, to ask about NP-hardness, you'd need to formulate it as a decision problem, which would presumably mean adding an additional parameter $k$ (also in unary?) and asking whether the value is at least $k$.  With these assumptions, the corresponding language is sparse, so is not NP-hard [unless P=NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_language).

Comment: I think sets A, B, C should also be taken as inputs？

Comment: But as you've defined the problem only the sizes of $A$, $B$, and $C$ matter, so the problem instance is fully specified by the single parameter $N$.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I see. On the other hand, is there any poly-time algorithm for answering this question?

Comment: The problem you give is not an integer programming, at least not one I know of. Moreover, it sounds to me more like a mathematical question, with no algorithmic flavor.